# Php getting id of current user not working

Tags: php, mysql, logging, xampp, session-variables

I was trying to make a page where you can log in and then change your nickname or/and password. Everything in mySQL database, but when I try to save the id to session variable, it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

I am using XAMPP, users is my table in database users, I'm not posting login form code, because it's very simple.

Everything is connected, code doesn't give any warnings or errors.

login.php (fragment):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname = '$myusername' and pass = '$mypassword' and confirmed = 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

  if($count == 1) {

        $logged = true;

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"];
            $_SESSION['currentId'] = $row["id"];
            echo 'Id: ' . $_SESSION['currentId'];
        }
  }else {
     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
  }
}
```

change.php (whole):

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "Users";
$currentId = $_SESSION['currentId'];

if($currentId<1){echo 'No Id.';}
else {echo 'CurrentId: ';
echo $currentId;}
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully <br>";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // username and password sent from form 

  $aCUname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['CUname']);
  $aCUpass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['CUpass']); 

  $sql = "UPDATE users SET nickname = '$aCUname', pass = '$aCUpass' WHERE id = '$currentId';";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    echo 'Updated successfully.';
}
?>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I for one, do not see any error handling of any sorts.

Comment: Could you please show the error message?

Comment: In your login.php code you are running mysql_fetch twice. The row pointer reaches the end once after running one mysql fetch. So remove the first one & try.

Comment: No error message. Id just behaves like it's null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution. I just had to delete

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

from login.php. Thanks to @Shashikumar Misal !